# Generic is lost when function is wrapped in a class

Tags: typescript, generics, polymorphism, typescript-generics

I'm writing a small utility for which I need to be able to express function composition using generics:

```
function compose<A, B, C>(f: (a: A) => B, g: (b: B) => C): (a: A) => C {
    return a => g(f(a));
}
```

In this case, TS seems to be able to "pass through" the type variables and infer the resulting type correctly:

```
const good = compose(<T>(t: T) => t, <T>(t: T) => t); // <T>(a: T) => T
```

My next step involves wrapping these functions in a class, so at a minimum, my composition function needs to return a wrapper:

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    constructor(public readonly value: T) { }
}

function wrapCompose<A, B, C>(f: (a: A) => B, g: (b: B) => C): Wrapper<(a: A) => C> {
    return new Wrapper(compose(f, g));
}
```

The type of `wrapCompose` is identical to `compose`, except that it wraps the result in a `Wrapper`. But now this is not typed correctly.

```
const bad = wrapCompose(<T>(t: T) => t, <T>(t: T) => t); // Wrapper<(a: unknown) => unknown>
```

Why is type inference breaking here? `Wrapper` doesn't do anything at all, so I'd expect its value to be typed using the exact same rules as if it was a plain value. Is there a way to wrap the result of my function such that TS correctly infers the result?

Comment: It doesn't work because [the support for higher order type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) implemented in [ms/TS#30215](//github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) only happens in certain specific conditions, and wrapping the returned function in an object breaks that.  As far as I know there's no way to "fix" it; arbitrary higher order function inference is a missing feature of TypeScript.  Does that address your question and I should write up an answer, or am I missing somehting?

Comment: @jcalz Bummer, so there's no workaround, like mixins or proxies? I guess not since it's a typing issue not a runtime one. Please go ahead and post it as an answer and I'll accept it.